# How to do validation while training using TPUEstimator

Tags: validation, tpu

I am using TPUEstimator for training.
My code is:

```
estimator = tf.contrib.tpu.TPUEstimator(use_tpu=FLAGS.use_tpu, model_fn=model_fn, config=run_config,` train_batch_size=FLAGS.train_batch_size, eval_batch_size=FLAGS.eval_batch_size, predict_batch_size=FLAGS.predict_batch_size)

estimator.train(input_fn=train_input_fn, max_steps=num_train_steps)
```

I tried using InMemoryEvaluatorHook.

```
train_hook = tf.estimator.experimental.InMemoryEvaluatorHook(estimator, eval_input_fn, steps=FLAGS.save_checkpoints_steps, every_n_iter=1)

estimator.train(input_fn=train_input_fn, max_steps=num_train_steps, hooks=[train_hook])
```

But I didn't get any result